# How to install docker-compose in jenkinsci/blueocean?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-blueocean

The `docker` image [jenkinsci/blueocean](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/blueocean/) seems official since the official document is mentioning the image.

I want to run `docker-compose` command in the container but this image only comes with `docker` but not `docker-compose`.

Thus, I tried to install `docker-compose` as the usual way inside the container.

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

It looked installed successfully, however, when I run `docker-compose --version`, it returns `bash: ./docker-compose: No such file or directory`, even though I can see the `docker-compose` executable at `$(which docker-compose)`.

(This error is not relative with `$PATH`, I tried to run directly at the directory where `docker-compose` is located)

How could I install `docker-compose` in the image, that is, how can I build new image containing `docker-compose` based on `jenkinsci/blueocean`?

Comment: Are you trying to run `docker-compose` as part of a job?

Comment: @SangminKim I am trying to do the same thing and am having the same issue as you. Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @jminardi, No I am just planning to try installing `Jenkins` over `Ubuntu` image including `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 4):

For me worked solution from ["INSTALL AS A CONTAINER"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-as-a-container) 
which is:

```
$ sudo curl -L --fail https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add glibc:

```
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean

USER root

RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN apk add ca-certificates wget && \
    wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    GLIBC_VERSION='2.27-r0' && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && apk add glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && apk add glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk
```

Comment: With the most recent blue ocean image, I found that glibc is built in. So the last 5 lines can be omitted. And for safety wouldn't it be better to close with `USER jenkins` to prevent the container running as root?